# drop down data to appear in form php

Tags: php

I have some data in db,now i m making them to display in the front end so,i ii have a update button,if i click it the selected values to come to database

dpaste.com/hold/180863

Thnx in advance.

Comment: listen to what Gordon said also your query is faulty `$result = mysql_query("SELECT FROM customers")` think about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chk does your query is giving you any output, here :`$result = mysql_query("SELECT FROM customers");`

echo ur query and paste in ur SQL query panel of ur PHPmyadmin. see do u get any value or not? if it does not then ur query is incorrect

u have not ended with proper tag here:

```
<? php


?>
```

"?>"

> **UPDATED**

```
<?php 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Customer"); while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ echo "Name: ".$row['0'].", Address:".$row['1'] .", City:".$row['city'].", pincode:".$row['pincode'].", State:".$row['state'].", Country:".$row['country'].", Phone:".$row['phone'].", Mobile:".$row['mobile'].", Fax:".$row['fax'].", Email:".$row['email'].", Website:".$row['url'].", Notes:".$row['notes']."; 

?>
```

u didnt put the "`>`" at the end in script u refrenced to

> **UPDATED**

DAF, your url : `http://localhost/up.php?customer=aaaaa,sssssssssssssss,aaaaaaa,22222Andhra+Pradesh,in,2222221,1111111,0,v@gmail.com,,`
is displaying all the values posted , its being appended in the url, I need to see the complete code you are working on

> **UPDATED**

```
      <html>
    <body>
    <form action="up.php">


    <?php

    // Create the connection and select the DB-->
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

    if ($con) {
       mysql_selectdb("form",$con);

       // Select records from the DB
       $query  = "SELECT * FROM customer";
       $result = mysql_query($query);

       // Display records from the table


       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

           $value = $row;

       }

    }


    ?>
       <p> 
          <label for="cname"><b>Name:</b></label>
 <em>*</em><input id="cname" name="name" size="25" class="required" value="<?php echo $value['name'];?>" minlength="5" />
                     </p> 




                  <p> 
               <label for="caddress"><b>Address:</b></label>
 <em>*</em><textarea id="caddress" name="address" cols="22" class="required" minlength="3" /><?php echo $value['address'];?></textarea>

                 </p>  


                <p>  
               <label for="ccity"><b>City/Town:</b></label>
 <em>*</em><input id="ccity" name="city" size="25" value="<?php echo $value['city'];?>" class="required" minlength="5" /> 
                  </p> 

                  <p> 
               <label for="cpincode"><b>Pincode:</b></label>
 <em>*</em><input id="cpincode" name="pincode" size="25" class="required" value="<?php echo $value['cpincode'];?>" digits="5" />

                </p> 

                <p> 
               <label for="cstate"><b>State:</b></label>


 <em>*</em><select class="state" id="cstate" name="state">
<option value=""   >Select One</option> 

                    <option <?php if($value['state'] == Andaman and Nicobar){ $selected = "selected='selected'";}else{$selected = "";} echo $selected;?>>Andaman and Nicobar</option> 
                    <option <?php if($value['state'] == Andhra Pradesh){ $selected = "selected='selected'";}else{$selected = "";} echo $selected;?>>Andhra Pradesh</option> 
                    <option <?php if($value['state'] == Arunachal Pradesh){ $selected = "selected='selected'";}else{$selected = "";} echo $selected;?>>Arunachal Pradesh</option> 
        ---
                ---
                ---- similar as above
                     </select> 

                  </p>  

                  <p> 
               <label for="ccountry"><b>Country:</b></label>

 <em>*</em><select class="country" id="ccountry" name="country"> 

// here as well do as above with $value['country']

                    <option value=""   >Select One</option> 
                    <option value="af"   >Afghanistan</option> 
                    <option value="ax"   >Aland Islands</option> 
                    <option value="al"   >Albania</option> 
                    <option value="dz"   >Algeria</option> 
                    <option value="as"   >American Samoa</option> 
                    <option value="ad"   >Andorra</option> 
                    <option value="ao"   >Angola</option> 
                    <option value="ai"   >Anguilla</option> 
                    <option value="aq"   >Antarctica</option> 
                    <option value="ag"   >Antigua and Barbuda</option> 
                    <option value="ar"   >Argentina</option> 
                    <option value="am"   >Armenia</option> 
                    <option value="aw"   >Aruba</option> 
                    <option value="au"   >Australia</option> 
                    <option value="at"   >Austria</option> 
                    <option value="az"   >Azerbaijan</option> 
                    <option value="bs"   >Bahamas</option> 
                    <option value="bh"   >Bahrain</option> 
                    <option value="bd"   >Bangladesh</option> 
                    <option value="bb"   >Barbados</option> 
                    <option value="by"   >Belarus</option> 
                    <option value="be"   >Belgium</option> 
                    <option value="bz"   >Belize</option> 
                    <option value="bj"   >Benin</option> 
                    <option value="bm"   >Bermuda</option> 
                    <option value="bt"   >Bhutan</option> 
                    <option value="bo"   >Bolivia</option> 
                    <option value="ba"   >Bosnia and Herzegovina</option> 
                    <option value="bw"   >Botswana</option> 
                    <option value="bv"   >Bouvet Island</option> 
                    <option value="br"  >Brazil</option> 
                    <option value="io"   >British Indian Ocean Territory</option> 
                    <option value="vg"   >British Virgin Islands</option> 
                    <option value="bn"   >Brunei</option> 
                    <option value="bg"   >Bulgaria</option> 
                    <option value="bf"   >Burkina Faso</option> 
                    <option value="bi"   >Burundi</option> 
                    <option value="kh"   >Cambodia</option> 
                    <option value="cm"   >Cameroon</option> 
                    <option value="ca"   >Canada</option> 
                    <option value="cv"   >Cape Verde</option> 
                    <option value="ky"   >Cayman Islands</option> 
                    <option value="cf"   >Central African Republic</option> 
                    <option value="td"   >Chad</option> 
                    <option value="cl"   >Chile</option> 
                    <option value="cn"   >China</option> 
                    <option value="cx"   >Christmas Island</option> 
                    <option value="cc"   >Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option> 
                    <option value="co"   >Colombia</option> 
                    <option value="km"   >Comoros</option> 
                    <option value="cg"   >Congo</option> 
                    <option value="ck"   >Cook Islands</option> 
                    <option value="cr"   >Costa Rica</option> 
                    <option value="hr"   >Croatia</option> 
                    <option value="cu"   >Cuba</option> 
                    <option value="cy"   >Cyprus</option> 
                    <option value="cz"   >Czech Republic</option> 
                    <option value="cd"   >Democratic Republic of Congo</option> 
                    <option value="dk"   >Denmark</option> 
                    <option value="xx"   >Disputed Territory</option> 
                    <option value="dj"   >Djibouti</option> 
                    <option value="dm"   >Dominica</option> 
                    <option value="do"   >Dominican Republic</option> 
                    <option value="tl"   >East Timor</option> 
                    <option value="ec"   >Ecuador</option> 
                    <option value="eg"   >Egypt</option> 
                    <option value="sv"   >El Salvador</option> 
                    <option value="gq"   >Equatorial Guinea</option> 
                    <option value="er"   >Eritrea</option> 
                    <option value="ee"   >Estonia</option> 
                    <option value="et"   >Ethiopia</option> 
                    <option value="fk"   >Falkland Islands</option> 
                    <option value="fo"   >Faroe Islands</option> 
                    <option value="fm"   >Federated States of Micronesia</option> 
                    <option value="fj"   >Fiji</option> 
                    <option value="fi"   >Finland</option> 
                    <option value="fr"   >France</option> 
                    <option value="gf"   >French Guyana</option> 
                    <option value="pf"   >French Polynesia</option> 
                    <option value="tf"   >French Southern Territories</option> 
                    <option value="ga"   >Gabon</option> 
                    <option value="gm"   >Gambia</option> 
                    <option value="ge"   >Georgia</option> 
                    <option value="de"   >Germany</option> 
                    <option value="gh"   >Ghana</option> 
                    <option value="gi"   >Gibraltar</option> 
                    <option value="gr"   >Greece</option> 
                    <option value="gl"   >Greenland</option> 
                    <option value="gd"   >Grenada</option> 
                    <option value="gp"   >Guadeloupe</option> 
                    <option value="gu"   >Guam</option> 
                    <option value="gt"   >Guatemala</option> 
                    <option value="gn"   >Guinea</option> 
                    <option value="gw"   >Guinea-Bissau</option> 
                    <option value="gy"   >Guyana</option> 
                    <option value="ht"   >Haiti</option> 
                    <option value="hm"   >Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands</option> 
                    <option value="hn"   >Honduras</option> 
                    <option value="hk"   >Hong Kong</option> 
                    <option value="hu"   >Hungary</option> 
                    <option value="is"   >Iceland</option> 
                    <option value="in"   SELECTED  >India</option> 
                    <option value="id"   >Indonesia</option> 
                    <option value="ir"   >Iran</option> 
                    <option value="iq"   >Iraq</option> 
                    <option value="xe"   >Iraq-Saudi Arabia Neutral Zone</option> 
                    <option value="ie"   >Ireland</option> 
                    <option value="il"   >Israel</option> 
                    <option value="it"   >Italy</option> 
                    <option value="ci"   >Ivory Coast</option> 
                    <option value="jm"   >Jamaica</option> 
                    <option value="jp"   >Japan</option> 
                    <option value="jo"   >Jordan</option> 
                    <option value="kz"   >Kazakhstan</option> 
                    <option value="ke"   >Kenya</option> 
                    <option value="ki"   >Kiribati</option> 
                    <option value="kw"   >Kuwait</option> 
                    <option value="kg"   >Kyrgyzstan</option> 
                    <option value="la"   >Laos</option> 
                    <option value="lv"   >Latvia</option> 
                    <option value="lb"   >Lebanon</option> 
                    <option value="ls"   >Lesotho</option> 
                    <option value="lr"   >Liberia</option> 
                    <option value="ly"   >Libya</option> 
                    <option value="li"   >Liechtenstein</option> 
                    <option value="lt"   >Lithuania</option> 
                    <option value="lu"   >Luxembourg</option> 
                    <option value="mo"   >Macau</option> 
                    <option value="mk"   >Macedonia</option> 
                    <option value="mg"   >Madagascar</option> 
                    <option value="mw"   >Malawi</option> 
                    <option value="my"   >Malaysia</option> 
                    <option value="mv"   >Maldives</option> 
                    <option value="ml"   >Mali</option> 
                    <option value="mt"   >Malta</option> 
                    <option value="mh"   >Marshall Islands</option> 
                    <option value="mq"   >Martinique</option> 
                    <option value="mr"   >Mauritania</option> 
                    <option value="mu"   >Mauritius</option> 
                    <option value="yt"   >Mayotte</option> 
                    <option value="mx"   >Mexico</option> 
                    <option value="md"   >Moldova</option> 
                    <option value="mc"   >Monaco</option> 
                    <option value="mn"   >Mongolia</option> 
                    <option value="ms"   >Montserrat</option> 
                    <option value="ma"   >Morocco</option> 
                    <option value="mz"   >Mozambique</option> 
                    <option value="mm"   >Myanmar</option> 
                    <option value="na"   >Namibia</option> 
                    <option value="nr"   >Nauru</option> 
                    <option value="np"   >Nepal</option> 
                    <option value="nl"   >Netherlands</option> 
                    <option value="an"   >Netherlands Antilles</option> 
                    <option value="nc"   >New Caledonia</option> 
                    <option value="nz"   >New Zealand</option> 
                    <option value="ni"   >Nicaragua</option> 
                    <option value="ne"   >Niger</option> 
                    <option value="ng"   >Nigeria</option> 
                    <option value="nu"   >Niue</option> 
                    <option value="nf"   >Norfolk Island</option> 
                    <option value="kp"   >North Korea</option> 
                    <option value="mp"   >Northern Mariana Islands</option> 
                    <option value="no"   >Norway</option> 
                    <option value="om"   >Oman</option> 
                    <option value="pk"   >Pakistan</option> 
                    <option value="pw"   >Palau</option> 
                    <option value="ps"   >Palestinian Occupied Territories</option> 
                    <option value="pa"   >Panama</option> 
                    <option value="pg"   >Papua New Guinea</option> 
                    <option value="py"   >Paraguay</option> 
                    <option value="pe"   >Peru</option> 
                    <option value="ph"   >Philippines</option> 
                    <option value="pn"   >Pitcairn Islands</option> 
                    <option value="pl"   >Poland</option> 
                    <option value="pt"   >Portugal</option> 
                    <option value="pr"   >Puerto Rico</option> 
                    <option value="qa"   >Qatar</option> 
                    <option value="re"   >Reunion</option> 
                    <option value="ro"   >Romania</option> 
                    <option value="ru"   >Russia</option> 
                    <option value="rw"   >Rwanda</option> 
                    <option value="sh"   >Saint Helena and Dependencies</option> 
                    <option value="kn"   >Saint Kitts and Nevis</option> 
                    <option value="lc"   >Saint Lucia</option> 
                    <option value="pm"   >Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option> 
                    <option value="vc"   >Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option> 
                    <option value="ws"   >Samoa</option> 
                    <option value="sm"   >San Marino</option> 
                    <option value="st"   >Sao Tome and Principe</option> 
                    <option value="sa"   >Saudi Arabia</option> 
                    <option value="sn"   >Senegal</option> 
                    <option value="sc"   >Seychelles</option> 
                    <option value="sl"   >Sierra Leone</option> 
                    <option value="sg"   >Singapore</option> 
                    <option value="sk"   >Slovakia</option> 
                    <option value="si"   >Slovenia</option> 
                    <option value="sb"   >Solomon Islands</option> 
                    <option value="so"   >Somalia</option> 
                    <option value="za"   >South Africa</option> 
                    <option value="gs"   >South Georgia and South Sandwich Islands</option> 
                    <option value="kr"   >South Korea</option> 
                    <option value="es"   >Spain</option> 
                    <option value="pi"   >Spratly Islands</option> 
                    <option value="lk"   >Sri Lanka</option> 
                    <option value="sd"   >Sudan</option> 
                    <option value="sr"   >Suriname</option> 
                    <option value="sj"   >Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option> 
                    <option value="sz"   >Swaziland</option> 
                    <option value="se"   >Sweden</option> 
                    <option value="ch"   >Switzerland</option> 
                    <option value="sy"   >Syria</option> 
                    <option value="tw"   >Taiwan</option> 
                    <option value="tj"   >Tajikistan</option> 
                    <option value="tz"   >Tanzania</option> 
                    <option value="th"   >Thailand</option> 
                    <option value="tg"   >Togo</option> 
                    <option value="tk"   >Tokelau</option> 
                    <option value="to"   >Tonga</option> 
                    <option value="tt"   >Trinidad and Tobago</option> 
                    <option value="tn"   >Tunisia</option> 
                    <option value="tr"   >Turkey</option> 
                    <option value="tm"   >Turkmenistan</option> 
                    <option value="tc"   >Turks And Caicos Islands</option> 
                    <option value="tv"   >Tuvalu</option> 
                    <option value="ug"   >Uganda</option> 
                    <option value="ua"   >Ukraine</option> 
                    <option value="ae"   >United Arab Emirates</option> 
                    <option value="uk"   >United Kingdom</option> 
                    <option value="xd"   >United Nations Neutral Zone</option> 
                    <option value="us"   >United States</option> 
                    <option value="um"   >United States Minor Outlying Islands</option> 
                    <option value="uy"   >Uruguay</option> 
                    <option value="vi"   >US Virgin Islands</option> 
                    <option value="uz"   >Uzbekistan</option> 
                    <option value="vu"   >Vanuatu</option> 
                    <option value="va"   >Vatican City</option> 
                    <option value="ve"   >Venezuela</option> 
                    <option value="vn"   >Vietnam</option> 
                    <option value="wf"   >Wallis and Futuna</option> 
                    <option value="eh"   >Western Sahara</option> 
                    <option value="ye"   >Yemen</option> 
                    <option value="zm"   >Zambia</option> 
                    <option value="zw"   >Zimbabwe</option> 
                    <option value="rs"   >Serbia</option> 
                    <option value="me"   >Montenegro</option> 
               </select> 

                  </p> 

                 <p> 
               <label for="cphone"><b>Phone:</b></label>
 <em>*</em><input id="cphone" name="phone" size="25" value="<?php echo $value['phone'];?>" class="required" digits="4" />

                </p> 

                   <p> 
               <label for="cmobile"><b>Mobile:</b></label>
 <em>*</em><input id="cmobile" name="mobile" value="<?php echo $value['mobile'];?>" size="25" class="required" digits="4" />
                 </p> 

          <P>
               <label for="num"><b>Fax:</b></label>
 <em>&nbsp; </em ><input id="cnum" name="fax" size="25" class="num"  value="<?php echo $value['fax'];?>" digits="10"  />
                  </p>

        <p> 
               <label for="cemail"><b>Email:</b></label>
            <em>*</em><input id="cemail" name="email" size="25" value="<?php echo $value['email'];?>" class="email" />
                  </p>


                  <p> 
               <label for="curl"><b>Website:</b></label>
            <em>&nbsp; </em><input id="curl" name="url" size="25" value="<?php echo $value['url'];?>" class="url" value="" />
                  </p>



                <p> 
        <label for="cnotes"><b>Notes:</b></label>
         <em>&nbsp; </em><textarea id="cnotes" name="notes" cols="22"  class="notes" /><?php echo $value['notes'];?></textarea>
         </p> 



    <input type ="submit" value="update" />
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: u have not ended with proper tag here:

<? php


?

"?>"

Comment: @Parth
<? php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Customer");   
 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   echo "Name: ".$row['0'].", Address:".$row['1']
       .", City:".$row['city'].", pincode:".$row['pincode'].", State:".$row['state'].", Country:".$row['country'].", Phone:".$row['phone'].", Mobile:".$row['mobile'].", Fax:".$row['fax'].", Email:".$row['email'].", Website:".$row['url'].", Notes:".$row['notes'].";
 
"?>"




IS,this way?

Comment: @perth but now,i added it.Its is displaying empty page,it isn't displaying those data present in drop down box but it is going to url,like this   http://localhost/up.php?customer=aaaaa%2Csssssssssssssss%2Caaaaaaa%2C22222Andhra+Pradesh%2Cin%2C2222221%2C1111111%2C0%2Cv%40gmail.com%2C%2C

Comment: @DAF Chk out my Updated reply above

Comment: @DAFFODIL the code between line 445 and 450 will not display the select box, because of the illegal way of display.

It will give u the value in select box like "Name, Address, City, Pincode, State, Country, Phone, Mobile, Fax, Email, Website, Notes"

Comment: make that data which is present in url to appear in form.

Comment: @DAFFODIL correct the code in lines 445-450 u will get what u want

Comment: @DAFFODIL also cross check the name of table u have written in query, its spelling, its case(uppercase/lowercase) as initially u have spelled customer table as "customer" and at the end "Customer" difference is in "c"..

Comment: @DAFFODIL ur url is displaying same thing what u have done in 445-450 correct it

Comment: @DAFFODIL chk the Updated answer above

Comment: @DAFF try to evaluate ur code urself buddy, everytime if u ask for solution then it will not help u to be self dependent.

Comment: It's displaying array in drop dwn box.I want it to get in to forms fields.The previous one was crt.

Comment: after while loop i suggested do this and tell me what do u get? 

echo "<pre>";
print_r($cust);

Comment: YOu have seen those data getting into url,i want them to get in to form fields.Thnx a lot.I dn't get ans but u have helped me a lot.

Comment: On emore More thing do u need the inserted data to be displayed in their respective fields likewise, name to displayed in name text box, address in address text, and Country selected in countryu list, is that what ur looking for?

Comment: Will be back by 2:15 buddy i will give u what u want, going for lunch :P pls do wait

Comment: Now follow it u will probably get what u wnat

Comment: m getting error on line 65.wen i voteed,it is saying need vote up require 15 reputation.thnx a lot for ething.my name is vijay

Answer (score 0):

you're query should be atleast

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT column FROM customers")
```

or

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers")
```